# Translate Delphi export to C#/Vb.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, delphi, pinvoke

I'm writting a simple wrapper of the **[Subtitle Workshop](http://subworkshop.sourceforge.net/download.php)** library, but I get stuck translating this Delphi export to C# or Vb.Net:

```
procedure GetSubtitleText(Time: Integer; Text: {$IFDEF UTF8}PWideChar{$ELSE}PChar{$ENDIF}; var BufferLen: Integer); stdcall;
var
  FText : {$IFDEF UTF8}WideString{$ELSE}String{$ENDIF};
begin
  FText := DisplaySubtitle(Subtitles, Time);

  if BufferLen > 0 then
{$IFDEF UTF8}
//    Text := Copy(FText, 1, BufferLen)
    Text := StringToWideChar(FText, Text, BufferLen)
{$ELSE}
    StrLCopy(Text, PChar(FText), BufferLen)
{$ENDIF}
  else
    BufferLen := Length(FText);
end;
```

I'm not understanding how to translate the conditionals of the `Text` parameter.

This is what I did:

```
<SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
<DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="GetSubtitleText", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Friend Shared Sub GetSubtitleText(
       <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal time As Integer,
       <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal text As StringBuilder,
       <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef bufferLength As Integer
)
End Sub
```

It seems to work as expected, however, I would like to ensure that I wrote it correctly.

Comment: The Delphi code is quite odd. The author seems not to know the difference between UTF8 and UTF16. The call to `StrLCopy` passes the wrong buffer length, it should pass `BufferLen - 1` due to a very poor design of that RTL function. The code should set BufferLen to the number of characters copied, but does not. Your calling code should call first with BufferLen of 0 to find out what size to allocate. Do you know what Delphi version compiled the code? Do you know whether UTF8 was defined?

Comment: @David Heffernan Thankyou for the info, I don't know those details, sorry, however it it helps for something, in a .drc file of the source code it has marked **VER150** of the Borland Delphi Pascal Compiler in what seems an auto-generated code.

Comment: VER150 is Delphi 7.  The code will not work in a Unicode Delphi.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been asked on the Code Review website instead?

Comment: @JerryDodge verification of code is off-topic on Code Review. It's mandatory that OP has a certain degree of confidence in their code, before we review it. For more information you could refer to [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is fine, so long as `UTF8` is not defined when the Delphi code was compiled. If `UTF8` is defined then you would need to marshal as `LPWStr`. And I have to assume that the Delphi code is compiled with an ANSI version of Delphi, so that `PChar` maps to `PAnsiChar`. The Delphi code will be totally broken if you try to compile it with Delphi 2009 or later.

There's not much point in specifying `CharSet.Ansi` if you explicitly mark every parameter with an explicit `MarshalAs` attribute.

The Delphi code is quite odd. The author seems not to know the difference between UTF-8 and UTF-16. In Delphi `PWideChar` and `WideString` are UTF-16 encoded. The call to `StrLCopy` passes the wrong buffer length, it should pass `BufferLen - 1` due to a very poor design of that RTL function. The code should also set `BufferLen` to the number of characters copied, but does not.

You can work around that in your .net code. I'll write C# because that's what I know. I'm sure that you will understand it:

```
int len = 0;
GetSubtitleText(time, null, len);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
len++; // work around poor design/use of StrLCopy 
GetSubtitleText(time, sb, len);
```

On the face of it, I would be somewhat sceptical of this Delphi code. You should be on your guard. At least you have the source code for it!

Answer (score -1):

I just would like to share the P/Invokes that I wrote in Vb.Net:

```
' ***********************************************************************
' Author   : Elektro
' Modified : 18-March-2016
' ***********************************************************************

#Region " Public Members Summary "

#Region " Functions "

' OpenFile(String, Single, Integer, Boolean, Boolean) As Boolean
' SaveFile(String, Integer, Single, Integer, Integer) As Boolean

' GetPlaybackDelay() As Integer
' SetAbsoluteDelay(Integer, Integer, Integer) As Boolean

' GetFormatIndex(String) As Integer
' GetFormatInformation(Integer, StringBuilder, StringBuilder, Integer, Integer) As Boolean

' GetSubtitleLineCount() As Integer
' GetSubtitleLine(Integer, Integer, Integer, StringBuilder, Integer) As Boolean

' AddSubtitleLine(Integer, Integer, String) As Integer
' InsertSubtitleLine(Integer, Integer, Integer, String) As Boolean
' DeleteSubtitleLine(Integer) As Boolean
' CreateNewSubtitleLine()

#End Region

#Region " Methods "

' ClearSubtitleLines()
' CloseFile()
' GetCurrentFormatName(StringBuilder, Integer, Integer)
' GetFormatName(Integer, StringBuilder, Integer)
' GetSubtitleText(Integer, StringBuilder, Integer)
' SetPlaybackDelay(Integer)

#End Region

#End Region

#Region " Option Statements "

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

#End Region

#Region " Imports "

Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security

#End Region

#Region " P/Invoke "

Namespace SubtitleWorkshop.Interop

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Platform Invocation methods (P/Invoke), access unmanaged code.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' This class suppresses stack walks for unmanaged code permission. 
    ''' <see cref="System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute"/> is applied to this class.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' This class is for methods that are safe for anyone to call.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Callers of these methods are not required to perform a full security review to make sure that the 
    ''' usage is secure because the methods are harmless for any caller.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' <see href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182161.aspx"/>
    ''' </remarks>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
    Friend NotInheritable Class SafeNativeMethods

#Region " Methods "

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Opens the specified subtitle file.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="filepath">
        ''' The source subtitle filepath.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="fps">
        ''' The subtitle FPS.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="formatIndex">
        ''' The subtitle format index.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="append">
        ''' If <see langword="True"/>, appends to the end of the subtitle file.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="reCalcTimeValues">
        ''' If <see langword="True"/>, recalculates the time values of the subtitle.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' <see langword="True"/> if the specified subtitle file was open successfully, otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="LoadSubtitleFile", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function OpenFile(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal filepath As String,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)> ByVal fps As Single,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal formatIndex As Integer,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal append As Boolean,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal reCalcTimeValues As Boolean
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Closes the current subtitle file.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="CloseSubtitleFile", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Sub CloseFile()
        End Sub

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Saves (or converts) the current subtitle file.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="filepath">
        ''' The target subtitle filepath.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="formatIndex">
        ''' The target subtitle format.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="fps">
        ''' The target subtitle FPS.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="fromIndex">
        ''' The starting index to copy from the source subtitle lines.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="toIndex">
        ''' The ending index to copy from the source subtitle lines.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' <see langword="True"/> if the operation success, otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="SaveSubtitleFile", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function SaveFile(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal filepath As String,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal formatIndex As Integer,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)> ByVal fps As Single,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal fromIndex As Integer,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal toIndex As Integer
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the format index of the specified subtitle format name.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="formatName">
        ''' The name of the subtitle format.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' The subtitle format index.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="GetFormatIndex", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function GetFormatIndex(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal formatName As String
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the format name of the specified subtitle format index.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="formatIndex">
        ''' The index of the subtitle format.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="buffer">
        ''' The string buffer to store the the subtitle format name.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="refBufferLength">
        ''' A by-reference variable that indicates the length of <paramref name="buffer"/>.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="GetFormatName", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Sub GetFormatName(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal formatIndex As Integer,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal buffer As StringBuilder,
                                        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef refBufferLength As Integer
        )
        End Sub

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets information of the specified subtitle format index.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="formatIndex">
        ''' The index of the subtitle format.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="bufferDescription">
        ''' The string buffer to store the the subtitle format description.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="bufferExtensions">
        ''' The string buffer to store the the subtitle format extensions.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="refBufferDescriptionLength">
        ''' A by-reference variable that indicates the length of <paramref name="bufferDescription"/>.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="refBufferExtensionsLength">
        ''' A by-reference variable that indicates the length of <paramref name="bufferExtensions"/>.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' <see langword="True"/> if the operation success, otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="GetFormatInformation", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function GetFormatInformation(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal formatIndex As Integer,
                                                    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal bufferDescription As StringBuilder,
                                                    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal bufferExtensions As StringBuilder,
                                                    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef refBufferDescriptionLength As Integer,
                                                    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef refBufferExtensionsLength As Integer
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the subtitle format name of the current subtitle file.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="buffer">
        ''' The string buffer to store the the subtitle format name.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="refIndex">
        ''' A by-reference variable that stores the subtitle format name.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="refBufferLength">
        ''' A by-reference variable that indicates the length of <paramref name="buffer"/>.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="GetCurrentFormat", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Sub GetCurrentFormatName(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal buffer As StringBuilder,
                                               <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef refIndex As Integer,
                                               <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef refBufferLength As Integer
        )
        End Sub

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the line count of the current subtitle file.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' The line count.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="GetSubtitleCount", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function GetSubtitleLineCount(
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the subtitle text at the specified time on the current subtitle file. 
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="time">
        ''' The time, in milliseconds.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="buffer">
        ''' The string buffer to store the the subtitle text.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="refBufferLength">
        ''' A by-reference variable that indicates the length of <paramref name="buffer"/>.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="GetSubtitleText", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Sub GetSubtitleText(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal time As Integer,
                                          <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal buffer As StringBuilder,
                                          <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef refBufferLength As Integer
        )
        End Sub

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the subtitle text at the specified line of the current subtitle file. 
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="lineIndex">
        ''' The line index.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="refStartTime">
        ''' A by-reference variable that stores the starting subtitle time, in milliseconds.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="refEndTime">
        ''' A by-reference variable that stores the ending subtitle time, in milliseconds.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="buffer">
        ''' The string buffer to store the the subtitle text.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="refBufferLength">
        ''' A by-reference variable that indicates the length of <paramref name="buffer"/>.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' <see langword="True"/> if the operation success, otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="GetSubtitle", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function GetSubtitleLine(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal lineIndex As Integer,
                                               <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef refStartTime As Integer,
                                               <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef refEndTime As Integer,
                                               <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal buffer As StringBuilder,
                                               <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef refBufferLength As Integer
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Sets an absolute delay on the current subtitle file.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="time">
        ''' The delay, in milliseconds.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="fromLineIndex">
        ''' The starting subtitle line index.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="toLineIndex">
        ''' The ending subtitle line index.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' <see langword="True"/> if the operation success, otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="SetAbsoluteDelay", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function SetAbsoluteDelay(
                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal time As Integer,
                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal fromLineIndex As Integer,
                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal toLineIndex As Integer
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the playback delay of the current subtitle file.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' The playback delay, in milliseconds.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="GetPlaybackDelay", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function GetPlaybackDelay(
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Sets a playback delay on the current subtitle file.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="time">
        ''' The playback delay, in milliseconds.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="SetPlaybackDelay", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Sub SetPlaybackDelay(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal time As Integer)
        End Sub

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Adds a subtitle line at the specified time in the current subtitle file. 
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="startTime">
        ''' The starting subtitle time, in milliseconds.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="endTime">
        ''' The ending subtitle time, in milliseconds.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="text">
        ''' The subtitle text.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' 
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="AddSubtitle", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function AddSubtitleLine(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal startTime As Integer,
                                               <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal endTime As Integer,
                                               <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal text As String
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Adds a subtitle line at the specified time in the current subtitle file. 
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="lineIndex">
        ''' The index of the line where to insert the subtitle line.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="startTime">
        ''' The starting subtitle time, in milliseconds.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="endTime">
        ''' The ending subtitle time, in milliseconds.
        ''' </param>
        ''' 
        ''' <param name="text">
        ''' The subtitle text.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' <see langword="True"/> if the operation success, otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="InsertSubtitle", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function InsertSubtitleLine(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal lineIndex As Integer,
                                                  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal endTime As Integer,
                                                  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal startTime As Integer,
                                                  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal text As String
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Removes a subtitle line in the current subtitle file. 
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <param name="lineIndex">
        ''' The index of the subtitle line to remove.
        ''' </param>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <returns>
        ''' <see langword="True"/> if the operation success, otherwise, <see langword="False"/>.
        ''' </returns>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="DeleteSubtitle", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Function DeleteSubtitleLine(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal lineIndex As Integer
        ) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Clears all the subtitle lines in the current subtitle file. 
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="ClearSubtitles", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Sub ClearSubtitleLines()
        End Sub

        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Create a new subtitle. 
        ''' </summary>
        ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity>
        <DllImport("SubtitleAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="CreateNewSubtitle", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
        Friend Shared Sub CreateNewSubtitleLine()
        End Sub

#End Region

    End Class

End Namespace

#End Region
```